Singular value decomposition - related problems
I ask some easy questions/advise to help me get going. I'm not that "theory-strong".
Let $A = U\Sigma V^T$ be the singular value decomposition of $A$

Show that the column vectors of $V$ is a orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$, with the eigenvectors from $A^TA$

Isn't this just the definition of how to make the decomposition matrices? You find the eigenvectors from $A^TA$, normalize them, and put them in a matrix $V$. And also, the column vectors must be in $\mathbb{R}^n$ since eigenvectors from $A^TA$ is of length n (the dimension of $A^TA$ is n x n). And we have n such eigenvectors. So if we have n orthonormal vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ they form a orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ right?
Also, it is n distinct eigenvalues, since $A^TA$ is symmetric. I believe this means n orthogonal eigenvectors?

Show that the column vectors of $U$ is a orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^m$, with the eigenvectors from $AA^T$

$U$ is constructed with the vectors from $V$, with multiplication by $A$ (and scaling). So the $v_i$'s from $V$ is an orthonormal set. Why do this mean that multiplication with $A$ preserves this orthonormality? If $A = \vec{0}$ (zero matrix), this wouldn't be correct... (I know that it must be correct, I'm just making a point in order to learn...)


Your reasoning is correct. One minor detail: $A^\top A$ being symmetric does not mean it has $n$ distinct eigenvalues. It means that $A^\top A$ has $n$ eigenvalues if you count them by multiplicity.

The way you define $U$ is by taking the eigenvectors $v_i$ you used to construct $V$ which have non-zero eigenvalue $\lambda_i$. You then define $u_i = A v_i / \sqrt{\lambda_i}$. This is not a basis yet, but we can prove that it is an orthonormal set of vectors. Any orthonormal set of vectors in $\mathbb R^m$ can be extended to an orthonormal basis, which yields the matrix $U$.
In order to prove that the initial vector $u_i$ are orthonormal, observe that
\begin{align*}
 u_i^\top u_j = (A v_i / \sqrt{\lambda_i})^\top (A v_j / \sqrt{\lambda_j})
 = \frac 1 {\sqrt{\lambda_i \lambda_j}} v_i^\top A^\top A v_j
 = \frac 1 {\sqrt{\lambda_i \lambda_j}} v_i^\top (\lambda_j v_j)
\end{align*}
If $i$ and $j$ are different, then $v_i^\top v_j = 0$, hence $u_i^\top u_j = 0$. If $i=j$, then the expression reduces to
\begin{align*}
 u_i^\top u_i = \frac{\lambda_i}{\sqrt{\lambda_i \lambda_i}} v_i^\top v_i = v_i^\top v_i = 1.
\end{align*}
This proves that the initial set of vectors $u_i$ is indeed orthonormal.


